# Introductions to discrete space-time

Tags: soft-question, spacetime, quantum-gravity, cellular-automaton

It's comparatively easy (cum grano salis) to grasp the following concepts:

- Euclidean space-time *(continous space and continuous time)*
- classical mechanics *(discretely distributed matter in continous space and continuous time)*
- Minkowskian space *(continously intermingled space and time)*
- special relativistic mechanics *(discretely distributed matter in continously intermingled space and time)*
- classical electrodynamics
- classical quantum mechanics *(discrete energies, continuously distributed matter in continous space and continuous time)*
- quantum electrodynamics
- general relativity *(continously intermingled space-time and matter)*

Accordingly, there are lots of introductory texts and text-books.

It's also easy to grasp

- numerical simulations *(on artificially - and mostly unphysically - discretized spaces, times, and space-times)*
- cellular automata *(on unphysical regular spatial grids)*

It's definitely hard to grasp (for somehow graspable reasons)

- quantum gravity

I do not know whether there are empirical evidences for a discrete space-time or only theoretical desiderata, anyhow I cannot figure a discrete space and/or time out.

Why is it so hard to introduce and explain the concept of a physical discrete space-time?

Why are there no easy to understand
introductory texts or text-books on definitions,
concepts, models, pros and cons of
discrete space, time, and - finally -
space-time?

Respectively: *Where are they?*

Are the reasons for this maybe related to the reasons why quantum gravity is so hard to grasp?

Comment: This doesn't look like a question so much as a personal theory/prejudice rephrased as a grammatical question.

Comment: So, not taking the question seriously - as it was posed - means: understanding discrete space, time, and space-time is in principle as "easy" as any of the "easy" concepts listed above? So, please just help me to learn and give me *one* introductory text - as there are many for any of the other subjects.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking for. If you want to learn about discrete quantum gravity theories (like LQG) then try to ask specifically about the concrete theory. Or ask about what approaches exist. Or perhaps do you want to learn about discretization in general? Because that is done all the time e.g. in condensed matter physics (think crystals) and lattice QFT (either space or time or both can be discretized). Although in lattice QFT there it's understood that discrete model is just an approximation to a continuous model.

Comment: Why do I have to dive *immediately* into loop-QG or lattice-QFT - rather advanced theories? When you start doing physics, it is presumed that you know the (continuous) Euclidean space. You approach QFT and QG via classical, relativistic, quantum mechanics and field theories, always presuming a continuous space-time. And suddenly I am supposed to be acquainted with a general notion of "discrete space(-time)"? Why can't we start with "discrete space" at the level of Euclidean space: How can Euclidean geometry be the classical limit of a discrete geometry?

Comment: @Hans: because "discrete geometry" is a much harder concept. What is usually meant by geometry is the space having a Lie (that is continuous) group acting on it. Or more generally, Riemannian geometry (of which the previous part is a homogenous case). But where do you get symmetries in discrete spaces? You lose almost all the rotations on the lattice (except for few that preserve it). So you lose Lorentz invariance and the theory is immediately shaky. To make the theory look at least a little like physics you have to introduce very nontrivial concepts. Does that answer your question?

Comment: No, that's the starting point of my question. Given the discrepancies between continuous and discrete geometries you mention: How can I - as a layman - only *think* about discrete geometries? And what are the "very nontrivial concepts" you mention? Can't they be introduced gently?

Comment: @Marek: "Where do you get symmetries in discrete spaces?" That's exactly the kind of questions I want to see answered. Or a prove why we never will get such a symmetry. (But maybe we have to change our concept of a symmetry?)

Comment: Why are you assuming (or at least I think you are?) that quantum gravity has anything to do with discrete space and time? It probably doesn't.

Comment: @Matt: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_quantum_gravity. Maybe I am mixing up "discrete" and "quantized"?

Comment: Quantum doesn't always imply discrete. There are some marginal research areas that try to start from discrete spacetime to study quantum gravity, but it doesn't have to be that way -- it isn't the case in string theory, for instance. There's also a strong argument from experiment that we have extremely good evidence against violations of Lorentz symmetry, and it's hard to imagine how a theory that had discrete spacetime at small scales (breaking that symmetry badly) would be consistent with observations.

Comment: @Matt: Do you have a reference where the conceptual differences between "quantized" and "discrete" are clarified?

Comment: @Matt: By the way: Google Scholar finds ~600 documents with "quantized space-time", but ~2,200 with "discrete space-time". What would *you* be searching for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like [Regge Calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regge_calculus) (there are plenty of extra refs in this link, and many more in [this one](http://scienceworld.wolfram.com/physics/ReggeCalculus.html)).

You can also check this article, [Quantum Gravity and Regge Calculus](http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9701052).

Furthermore, [this guy](http://ccom.ucsd.edu/~astern/) has a whole research area in this topic (discrete spaces, etc)!

So, there's **plenty** of stuff out there... you just have to look. ;-)

(**Edited**) PS: In fact, here's the name of the game: [Discrete Differential Geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_differential_geometry). Google away...

Comment: There's also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_dynamical_triangulation

Comment: @mtrencseni: Yup. But, i think you can understand CDTs as a Discrete Differential Geometry endowed with a Causal Structure. So, in the sense of "reducing to the basics", i think it'd be best to understand what it means to discretize geometrical objects (eg, Diff Forms), and then add causality to the mix.